# Lettuce test with django and selenium no run on windows

Tags: django, testing, selenium, suite, lettuce

I have a lettuce test suite using selenium and everything works just fine on linux.

After I installed django and everything that's needed on windows to test the suite on IE8,9 too, and I tried to run the test, it only opens my browser and says that the test passed with 0 features, 0 steps etc. The same test suite on linux runs just fine.

What do I need to make them work on windows 7 too ???

I use python for my test.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the best solution for you problem, I'm not even sure that it's valid for IE, but you could try to launch IE remotely so you will not need to launch whole application on windows (i.e. if you were using gunicorn as wsgi server, you couldn't launch on windows at all).

Python-selenium has functionality to use remote browsers, I'm just not sure about IE.